# how to show search data after postback function call in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

gridview details show exactly what as i want even search data also show fine but problem is when i post back page and return on search page search is not maintain in gridview i use gridview.Databind() function on page load use (!page.postback) function but then also not useful for me so please can you all give me any code for that 
on page load  i write but not useful for me

```
if(!page.postback)
{
 sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Name,ContactNo,Address from gridviewtable",con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        gvd_detail.DataSource = ds;
        gvd_detail.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some solution :

1- After every user search , Redirect user to page with parameter( like query string) and then on that page retrieve parameter and show appropriate result

2-Asp.net pages by default maintain page state by "View-state" , First make sure ViewState property of the page is True , Then make sure in page life cycle where you have rebind gridview

3-If there is situation in which #2 solution didn't work , There are another solution and that is saving page state in ViewState page explicitly

Hope these help

Comment: thnx mostafa but if you don't mind can you give me code please its helpfull for me